# Having consistency set to 'all' and refresh set to true causing ElasticSearch to timeout

Tags: elasticsearch, timeout, refresh, consistency

Greetings overflowers,

I have create/update operations that require the writes to be synced to all replicas and their indexes to be refreshed, so I am using consistency: 'all' and refresh: true options. However, this is causing NodeJS elasticsearch client to always timeout (after 30000ms). Does it take that long? What is wrong?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a lot from Elastisearch. How many replicas do you have in your cluster?

If you have lot of replicas then having `write consistency` to `all` will take some time. Even if data integrity of utmost importance, I feel default value of `quorum` is enough.

Excellent source to understand [write consistency](http://exploringelasticsearch.com/advanced_techniques.html#uid130)

Last para from the above link

> If your primary data-store is not elasticsearch it is almost certain
>   that the all write-level is overkill. The performance impact will
>   likely not be worth the extra guarantees of durability. As a final
>   point, it should be noted that during a split-brain failure, where a
>   single cluster has divided into two due to either a network partition
>   or overloading, write-consistency guarantees will be rendered moot for
>   obvious reasons.

And because of that I dont think having consistency level to all will save you from disaster.

setting `refresh` to true is overkill as you will be opening and writing so many segments every millisecond. ES is almsot real time as it refreshes every shard automatically every second.

Have a look at Elasticsearch document of [Near Real Time](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html) Doc.

You will understand a lot from that.

If still you want to persist with those settings, then you need to increase timeout considerably from default value of 30 seconds.

Comment: How timeout can be increased?

Comment: you could refer to this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908484/how-to-fix-read-timed-out-elasticsearch  I still think remove refresh=true should solve your problem