# Read timeout error while using elastic search python package

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have installed `elasticsearch` python package and I have created a elastic clustere. I am using below python code to send data to elastic cloud:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
import time
import datetime

es = Elasticsearch(['70.19.172.110:9200'],http_auth=('<username>','<password>'))

for x in range(0,5):
    es.index(index='test', doc_type='json', id=x, body={
    'data1':"Hello World',
    'value':325,
    'time': datetime.datetime.now()

    })

    print("Data sent {} ".format(x))
    time.sleep(60)
```

So as you can see in the code I am sending the data with the interval of 1min `time.sleep(60)`. This works fine and all the 5 data's are in the elasticsearch. Then I changed the `time.sleep(60)` to `time.sleep(300)` and it gave me below error:

`elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionTimeout: ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeoutError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='70.19.172.110', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=10))`

Is there anything which I am doing wrong. Is there any way I can keep connected to the elasticsearch so that I dont't through these types of errors.

Thanks.

Comment: because the default timeout of Elasticsearch is 10 Second, Your Connection dont Reasch the host , you have 10 second for connect to the host Before Elasticsearch close the connection for Timeout

Comment: @SkillerDz Thanks, so you mean to say I have to do `es = Elasticsearch(['70.19.172.110:9200'],http_auth=('<username>','<password>'))` each time I am sending the data. But then how did it worked when I used 60sec.?

Comment: es.index(index='test', doc_type='json', id=x, body={
    'data1':"Hello World',
    'value':325,
    'time': datetime.datetime.now()
    'timeout':30 # The time of the Time Out
    })

Comment: you must add a new value to timeout on es.index

Comment: @SkillerDz I didnt get it. So you mean to say, for 5 min timeout, I have to add 300 as timeout value. Can you answer the question with explaination, so that I can also accept it

Comment: @SAndrew What I think happens is that you create a connection in the very beginning and if it is inactive for >60sec the server cuts it off. If you query every 5 min it's ok to create a new connection every time, so yes, moving creation of `Elasticsearch` object (and hence the connection) inside the loop should solve your problem.

Comment: Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908484/how-to-fix-read-timed-out-in-elasticsearch) question, it looks similar

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev Thanks for your response, Its working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to Up the timeout of es.index , because Elasticsearch are limited to 10 secondes of timeout , if on 30 Secondes it will not respond that mean your Host arn't connected or dont respond to the request

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection
import time
import datetime
timenow = datetime.datetime.now()

es = Elasticsearch(['70.19.172.110:9200'],http_auth=('<username>','<password>'))

for x in range(0,5):
   es.index(index='test', doc_type='json', id=x, body={
   'data1':"Hello World",
   'value':325,
   'time':timenow,
   'timeout':30, # The Time Of timeout you want

    })

print("Data sent {} ".format(x))
time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: I added the `'timeout':300` but it still throws the same error

Comment: I tryed The Script With the Ip My Routeur 192.168.1.1:80 with port 80 and the script worked fine with me , i think the probleme are on the host who you are tryng to reach , mabe the port 9200 are closed try another port